# AVAudioplayer Control using UISlider not Show progress When first time play

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, uislider

I am working on a custom audio player in using Xcode. But problem is that when first time i load the audio data Slider progress stop working though the `audioplayer.current` set properly to the `slider.value` ...

```
NSError *error2;
self.Audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songFile error:&error2];
if (!error2)
{
    Audioplayer.delegate = self;
    [Audioplayer play];
    self.progressSliderview.value = 0.0f;
    self.progressSliderview.maximumValue = Audioplayer.duration;
    currentTimeUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                              target:self selector:@selector(updateAudioDisplayplay1)
                                                            userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is the Audioplayer.duration getting updated as expected?

Comment: `updateAudioDisplayplay1`Put the code of this method

Comment: Its update each time but the Slider value not updated first time with the value of Audioplayer.duration. After first time its update according to the audio player.duration value